# @Html.DropDownList does not select value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In an asp.net mvc 4 web application i am using a viewmodel to load my data to the page, edit part of these data and update the relevant model.

At the moment I am stuck with an `@Html.DropDownList` that although it displays fine the dropdown list , it doesn't change/update according to what you select.

Any idea why is this happening and what I am doing wrong?

Below is my code :

Controller :

```
public ActionResult RequestDetails(int id)
{
  var details = from s in SystemDB.Events.ToList()
                where s.BookingId == id
                orderby s.EventId descending
                select s;
  List<RequestDetailsViewModel> result = new List<RequestDetailsViewModel>();
  foreach (var item in details)
  {
    RequestDetailsViewModel model = new RequestDetailsViewModel();
    model.Event.EventId = item.EventId;
    model.Event.EventLeader = item.EventLeader;
    model.Event.EventStartDateTime = item.EventStartDateTime;
    model.Event.EventEndDateTime = item.EventEndDateTime;
    model.Event.Room.RoomNumber = item.Room.RoomNumber;
    model.Event.EventTotalCost = item.EventTotalCost;
    model.Event.Booking.BookingId = item.BookingId;              
    result.Add(model);              
  }
  Booking booking = SystemDB.Bookings.Find(id);
  var statuscodes = from s in SystemDB.StatusCodes.ToList()
                    where s.StatusCodeId != 1
                    select s;
  ViewBag.StatusCodeList = new SelectList(statuscodes, "StatusCodeId", "StatusCodeName", booking.StatusCodeId);
  return View(result);
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("RequestDetails")]
public ActionResult PostRequestDetails(int id)
{
  var details = from s in SystemDB.Events.ToList()
                where s.BookingId == id
                orderby s.EventId descending
                select s;
  List<RequestDetailsViewModel> result = new List<RequestDetailsViewModel>();
  foreach (var item in details)
  {
    RequestDetailsViewModel model = new RequestDetailsViewModel();
    model.Event.EventId = item.EventId;
    model.Event.EventLeader = item.EventLeader;
    model.Event.EventStartDateTime = item.EventStartDateTime;
    model.Event.EventEndDateTime = item.EventEndDateTime;
    model.Event.Room.RoomNumber = item.Room.RoomNumber;
    model.Event.EventTotalCost = item.EventTotalCost;
    model.Event.Booking.BookingId = item.BookingId;             
    result.Add(model);
 }
 Booking booking = SystemDB.Bookings.Find(id);
 var statuscodes = from s in SystemDB.StatusCodes.ToList()
                   where s.StatusCodeId != 1
                   select s;
 ViewBag.StatusCodeList = new SelectList(statuscodes, "StatusCodeId", "StatusCodeName", booking.StatusCodeId);
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    SystemDB.Entry(booking).State = EntityState.Modified;
    SystemDB.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("RequestList", "Admin");
  }                
  return View(result);
}
```

Viewmodel :

```
public class RequestDetailsViewModel
{
  public RequestDetailsViewModel()
  {
    this.Event = new Event();
    this.CateringItem = new CateringItem();
    this.Item = new Item();
    this.Event.Room = new Room();
    this.Event.Booking = new Booking();
    this.Event.Booking.StatusCode = new StatusCode();
  }
  public Event Event { get; set; }
  public CateringItem CateringItem { get; set; }
  public Item Item { get; set; }  
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<CateringBookingSystem.ViewModels.RequestDetailsViewModel>

@Html.ActionLink("Manage Requests", "RequestList")/<b>Event List</b>

@using (Html.BeginForm("RequestDetails", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
  <span><b>Booking for: </b>@ViewBag.Date</span>
  <span style="padding-left:20px;"><b>Total Cost: </b>£@ViewBag.BookingTotalCost</span>
  <span style="padding-left:20px;"><b>Requester: </b><a href="mailto:'@ViewBag.RequesterEmail'?Subject=Catering%20enquiry" target="_top">@ViewBag.Requester</a></span>
  <span style="padding-left:20px;"><b>Status: </b> @Html.DropDownList("StatusCodeList")  </span>

  <table id="listTable" style="width:100%" >
    <tr style="color:white;">
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Event.EventLeader)</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Event.EventStartDateTime</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Event.EventEndDateTime</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Event.Room.RoomNumber)</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Event.EventTotalCost)</th>        
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
      <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Event.EventLeader)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Event.EventStartDateTime)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Event.EventEndDateTime</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Event.Room.RoomNumber)</td>
        <td>£@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Event.EventTotalCost</td>
      </tr>
    }
  </table>
  <div style="padding-top:50px;">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </div>
}

<div style="padding-top:20px;">
  <img src="~/Images/arrow-return-180-left.png" style="margin-bottom:-3px;margin-right:-4px;" /> @Html.ActionLink("Back to Requests", "RequestList")
</div>
```

Comment: What is the property your trying to bind to?

Comment: booking.StatusCodeId

Comment: And is that really your POST method (just posting back `int id` and not `List<RequestDetailsViewModel>`)?

Comment: I tried posting RequestDetailsViewModel without success as everything comes null : 

 [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("RequestDetails")]
        public ActionResult PostRequestDetails(RequestDetailsViewModel viewmodel)

Comment: The model your sending to the view is `List<RequestDetailsViewModel>` so the POST method would need to be `public ActionResult PostRequestDetails(List<RequestDetailsViewModel> viewmodel)`. Its a bit unclear what your trying to do?

Comment: Hi  , still comes as null even like that...

Comment: I have two models in a viewmodel , what i am trying to do is to display the data for the Event model and amend details for the Booking model that is related to the Events on the same page

Comment: No it wont if its done correctly using a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `RequestDetailsViewModel`. Normally a `for` loop will work but there is a known bug with using `DropDownListFor()` that means you need an `EditorTemplate`

Comment: Your last comment does not seem to relate to the view which is `List<RequestDetailsViewModel>`. Now I am even more confused what th view should actually be doing

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 @Html.DropDownList("StatusCodeList", (SelectList) ViewBag.StatusCodeList, "Select")
```

Comment: Nop , that doesnt work , doesnt select the value at all

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewBag.StatusCodeList is already the type of SelectList. I don't see a reason to create the SelectList twice, so shouldn't it just be:

```
@Html.DropDownList("StatusCodeList", ViewBag.StatusCodeList)
```

or

```
@Html.DropDownList("StatusCodeList", ViewBag.StatusCodeList as SelectList)
```

Comment: this one get an error : DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'StatusCodeId'.

Comment: Error 1 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CateringBookingSystem.ViewModels.RequestDetailsViewModel>>' has no applicable method named 'DropDownList' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You GET method is returning a collection of `RequestDetailsViewModel` to the view. To render the collection correctly for post back, use a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `RequestDetailsViewModel` and change your POST method to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RequestDetails(IEnumerable<RequestDetailsViewModel> model)
```

Note, In most cases you can use a `for` loop for rendering a collection in the view, but there is a bug in `DropDownListFor()` which prevents the control from binding correctly in a `for` loop (despite the value of the property your binding to, the first option will always be selected).

Editor template

/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/RequestDetailsViewModel.cshtml

```
@model RequestDetailsViewModel

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Event.Booking.EventId)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Event.Booking.EventLeader)
....
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Event.Booking.StatusCodeId, (SelectList)ViewData["StatusCodeList"], "-Please select-")
....
```

In the main view, you need to pass the `SelectList` to the template in the `additionalViewData` parameter

```
@model IEnumerable<RequestDetailsViewModel>
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m, new { StatusCodeList = (SelectList)ViewBag.StatusCodeList })
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

GET method

```
public ActionResult RequestDetails(int id)
{
  var model = SystemDB.Events
    .Where(e => e.BookingId == id)
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.EventId)
    .Select(e => new RequestDetailsViewModel()
    {
      Event.EventId = e.EventId,
      Event.EventLeader = e.EventLeader,
      ...
      Event.Booking.BookingId = e.BookingId;
      Event.Booking.StatusCodeId = // set this value - if it matches the value of one of the values in the select list, then that option will be selected
    });
  var statuscodes = SystemDB.StatusCodes.Where(s => s.StatusCodeId != 1);
  ViewBag.StatusCodeList = new SelectList(statuscodes, "StatusCodeId", "StatusCodeName"); // don't use 4th parameter
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is the solution , i have added the full view to help you understand what i am trying to do : 
Basically list all of the events related to a booking and then give the possibility to edit that booking on the same view, mainly the status drop down list... this is where i am stuck..

Comment: Your edits don't really relate to the question or subsequent comments. Why do you have all the code inside `@Html.BeginForm()` The only control you have is a `<select>` generated by `@Html.DropDownList("StatusCodeList")` which does not bind to anything. My best guess is the dropdown is used for filtering the list your displaying?

Comment: Basically i was thinking giving the user the possibility of editing on the spot each event as well except of the booking details that is displayed on the top. Thats why I have everything is one form...

Comment: For that your going to need a lot of javascript/jquery code, but what is the purpose of the dropdownlist? Your GET and POST methods seem almost identical and its hard to understand why you have all that code in the POST method. The only difference is your get a `Booking` based on the value and mark it as modified (even though you don't modify it in any way), then save it (why?). It should not be a POST if your not modifying data, and you can delete all the code in the method and just replace it with `return RedirectToAction("RequestDetails", new { id = id })` anyway.